# Istio EnvoyFilter - Wasm - Classifying Metrics Based on Request or Response

Tags: lua, istio, webassembly, envoyproxy, istio-sidecar

I am trying to insert a custom dimension for an istio metric for URL path.
I am following the steps here -
https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/classify-metrics/

Specifically, this part, where I can parse the URL and decide the value :

```
configuration:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.StringValue
                value: |
                  {
                    "attributes": [
                      {
                        "output_attribute": "istio_operationId",
                        "match": [
                          {
                            "value": "ListReviews",
                            "condition": "request.url_path == '/reviews' && request.method == 'GET'"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "GetReview",
                            "condition": "request.url_path.matches('^/reviews/[[:alnum:]]*$') && request.method == 'GET'"
                          },
                          {
                            "value": "CreateReview",
                            "condition": "request.url_path == '/reviews/' && request.method == 'POST'"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
```

I want to add a fall-back approach - i.e., if it doesn't match any URL, then make the value of istio_operationId as the original `request.url_path`

How can I do that?

I tried adding this as the last condition but it doesn't work

```
{
    "value": "request.url_path", //tried without quotes as well
    "condition": "request.url_path.matches('.+$')"
}
```

Also, is this possible in Lua?

Answer (score 1):

To set a fall back value leave the condition blank. From the [docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/proxy_extensions/attributegen/#Match) "An empty condition evaluates to true and should be used to provide a default value.".

That said, I don't think there's a way to set the attribute value to anything but a static string. What you can do instead is add the `url_path` as a dimension to one (or all) metrics generated by the stats filter. To say it another way, I don't think you can combine request classification with custom dimensions the way you're describing.

See [this blog post](https://blog.christianposta.com/understanding-istio-telemetry-v2/) for details as well as an explanation of the difference between attributes and dimensions.

Also, you may want to reconsider trying. When metrics are emitted with unbounded cardinality monitoring systems fall over. [Here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14642) is a description of an Istio user crashing their Prometheus instance this way. [Here](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/20369#issue-553052608) is the (then) co-lead of the Istio extensions and telemetry working group discussing why they do not recommend doing this.

Comment: So it looks like to achieve what I want (have a dimension for normalized URL) , I could have a http filter to parse URL and put the URL pattern into a header, and then create a new dimension and set it to the new header that I just created.

Comment: Yeah if you wanted to avoid cardinality explosion by regexing things into buckets in a more flexible way than attribute generation supports you could give that a go.